# All previous suggestions fail to load my partial view into a <div> on button click

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

All suggestions on this site regarding loading a Partial View in a div on a button click fail for me. They either do nothing or return an error. `@Html.Action` works within a div but no JavaScript/JQuery/Ajax solution works when a button is clicked

`@Html.Action` works within the div but not with javascript
`@Url.Action` doesn't work. Often gives an error that the string isn't  properly terminated
`@Url.Content` is no better than `@Url.Action`
`$("#divname").load()` returns an error that the object doesn't support "load"

**Button:**

```
<a onclick="Rabbit01()" href="#">Try This</a>
```

**JavaScript 1:**

```
function Rabbit01() {
    var wannabe = document.getElementById("whollyinsane");
    var url = '@Url.Action("QuestionLists")';
    var key = 1;
    wannabe.load(url, { id: key }); 
}
```

**JavaScript 2:**

```
function Rabbit01() {
     var url = '@Url.Action("QuestionLists")';
     var key = 1;
     $("#wannabe").load(url, { id: key }); // returns error regarding "load"
}
```

I expect the controller to respond to the `@Url.Action` (this works if I put `@Html.Action` in a di>) and for the resulting partial view to load in the "wannabe" div when the "Try This" button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
        function Rabbit01() {
            $("#divId").load('@(Url.Action("PartialViewLoadMethod","PartialViewControler"))', function(){});
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Nothing happens when I click the button to call the script:

Comment: function Rabbit01() {
        $("#whollyinsane").load('@(Url.Action("QuestionLists?id=1","MIRT_Main"))', function(){});
    }
Does nothing with or without the parameter (?id=1)

Comment: This doesn't work at all: `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Rabbit01() {
        $("#whollyinsane").innerHTML = "Hello!";
    }
'

Comment: Where as this does: `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Rabbit01() {
        var thisdiv = document.getElementById("whollyinsane"); thisdiv.innerHTML = "Hello!";
    }`